# Pyspark - filter dataframe and create rank columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a situation where I want to create   rank columns in a dataframe based on different conditions and set first rank as true and others as false. Below is a sample dataframe:

```
Column1    Column2   Column3   Column4
ABC        X1        null      2016-08-21 11:31:08
ABC        X1        Test      2016-08-22 11:31:08
ABC        X1        null      2016-08-20 11:31:08
PQR        X1        Test      2016-08-23 11:31:08
PQR        X1        Test      2016-08-24 11:31:08
PQR        X1        null      2016-08-24 11:31:08
```

Here I want to create Rank columns based on below conditions:

**Rank1:** *Calculate rank on Column1 for rows where Column2 is X1 and Column3 is null and order by Column4*

**Rank2:** *Calculate rank on Column1 for rows where Column2 is X1 and Column3 is Test and order by Column4*

So the expected outcome would be:

```
Column1    Column2   Column3   Column4                Rank1    Rank2
ABC        X1        null      2016-08-21 11:31:08    2        null
ABC        X1        Test      2016-08-22 11:31:08    null     1
ABC        X1        null      2016-08-20 11:31:08    1        null
PQR        X1        Test      2016-08-23 11:31:08    null     1
PQR        X1        Test      2016-08-24 11:31:08    null     2
PQR        X1        null      2016-08-24 11:31:08    1        null
```

I tried to do this using **when** to filter out data but then the rank were not starting from 1.

```
df = df.withColumn("Rank1", F.when((df.Column2 == 'X1') & (df.Column3.isNull()), rank().over(Window.partitionBy('Column1').orderBy('Column4')))
```

This does give me the sequential order but sequence is random. I need to label the first rank so it is important for me to know it.

Other option I tried was to filter data in a temporary dataframe and calculate rank and join it back to main dataframe. But the dataframe size is big and multiple columns are to be calculated so it is giving out of memory error. Any help on solving this problem would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the condition to the order by clause of the partitionby window.

This should work for you:

```
condition_rank1 = (col("column2") == 'X1') & (col("column3").isNull())
condition_rank2 = (col("column2") == 'X1') & (col("column3") == 'Test')

w_rank1 = Window.partitionBy('column1').orderBy(*[when(condition_rank1, lit(1)).desc(), col("column4")])
w_rank2 = Window.partitionBy('column1').orderBy(*[when(condition_rank2, lit(1)).desc(), col("column4")])

df.withColumn("Rank1", when(condition_rank1, rank().over(w_rank1))) \
    .withColumn("Rank2", when(condition_rank2, rank().over(w_rank2))) \
    .show()
```

Comment: thank you so much I've been looking for this everywhere.